# WordPress and jQuery problem

Tags: jquery, wordpress

i have problem in admin site in WordPress. Looks on not working jQuery there.
[image]

i use hosting from freehosting.com maybe this is a main problem.

Here is full resolution screend: [link text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3Q74.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are preferring a good free host without ads,, then i would suggest [dreamhostapps.com](http://dreamhostapps.com). They provide a very good server and one click install of modules like wordpress and many open source system.. But you need to pay if you want your own domain name... Check out it ..

Answer (score 0):

Probably you include your js file in admin and you are not supposed to.

If you use `wp_enqueue_script` (and if you don't, [you should](http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html)!) or any other `functions.php` method just make sure you don't include files when you are in admin area:

```
if(!is_admin()){
// load scripts here
}
```

Also, you are trying to compress all js files in one big file? If yes, you may reconsider this, as admin. :)

Btw, are you working on something like [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-minify/)?

Comment: Thank a lot with help but i install WordPress from script. I dont doing anything manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yore problem isn't including or not including admin JS files or using a plugin to minify; it's the free hosting. Spend a few dollars on webhosting and WordPress will work fine. Free hosting will always be problematic.

GoDaddy's free hosting works well, but will also create problems with WP's admin. But you can work around that with details in this thread:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/dashboardadmin-css-broken-godaddy-free-hosting-install/page/3?replies=102

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at what other plugins are installed. Those errors are coming from the standard set of WordPress scripts so I'd wager that there's bad code somewhere in a plugin file.